# Having two param lists with same size

Tags: c#, parameters

The method `PrintTimes(string a, int b)` prints the string `a`, `b` times (i.e. `PrintTimes("test",3)` will print `testtesttest`).

I want to create a method, which will get a `params` array of strings and a `params` array of integers. So the call function will ook like this

```
PrintTimes("A","B","C","D",2,1,3,2);
```

Or

```
PrintTimes("A",2,"B",1,"C",3,"D",2)
```

Both of which will print `AABCCCDD`

Since there can be only one `params` parameter in a method, this is impossible. So is there a way to do this?

I know I can create a Class with a string and an int variable, and create a `params` array for the class. But I'd rather not, since it would involve constructing a new Class for each set

Comment: You could make use of the Tuple class to avoid writing your own custom class. Something like `PrintTimes(params Tuple<string, int>[] args)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about just dropping the `params` keyword and taking arrays instead? That is, make the signature `PrintTimes(string[], int[])`. `PrintTimes(new[]{"A","B","C","D"}, new[]{2,1,3,2});` isn't that much more to write.

Answer (score 2):

Why not using a class

```
public class PrintParameter
{
    public int Count {get;set;}
    public string Content{get;set;}
}
```

Then

```
public void PrintTimes(List<PrintParameter> inputs)
{
    //for each input print the "Content", "Count" times
}
```

Or

```
public void PrintTimes(params PrintParameter[] inputs)
{
    //for each input print the "Content", "Count" times
}
```

If you don't want to define a class you may try something like `List<KeyValuePair<string,int>>` or other alternatives such as `List<Tuple<string,int>>` and etc. However the preferred way of doing is to use a class with meaningful properties.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can go about solving this problem.  While you can only have one `params`, you can just make both your parameters arrays:

```
PrintTimes(string[] strings, int[] printCounts)
{
    // Assert strings.Length == printCounts.Length
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < printCounts[i]; j++)
        {
            // Print strings[i]
        }
    }
}
```

Then it can be called like this:

```
int[] numbers = new int[3] {1, 2, 3};
string[] names = new string[3] {"Matt", "Joanne", "Robert"};
PrintTimes(names, numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Hossein's suggestion, why not something as simple as:

`void PrintTimes(List<String> strings, List<Int> count)`

(or do it as an array as the comments said) Then inside PrintTimes require the inputs to be the same length or some logical fail when they don't.